# DISABLETHEMES for application compatibility in windows 7 not working

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, c#

i am porting an legacy winform application developed for xp on windows 7 ,which is currently developed using c#.net 3.5 and some third party controls which are very old but don't want to change them as long as they are working fine. problem is controls not displayed correctly on winform, so we found solution is to DISABLETHEMES as mentioned in

```
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html
```

solution works when you right click on .exe file and set DISABLETHEMES . but it don't work when you manually make registry entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
key applicationpath
value  DISABLETHEMES
```

any body tell what i am missing

Comment: I don't think the compatibility shims are just in that one place in the Registry. Run Process Monitor from SysInternals to see what is actually being changed by the right-click action, and reproduce that.

Comment: same things works under current user that is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for solving problem 
i have to make registry entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
key applicationpath
value  DISABLETHEMES
```

and

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
key applicationpath
value  DISABLETHEMES
```

if you want same setting for all user on os.
for current user only setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER entry is sufficient.

when you make entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE somehow application exe dose not know it.
but when you make entry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER application instantly recognize settings.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it helps, I ran a trace  and this is what I get after a GUI change for a program called MyIE (myie.exe).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Net\\MyIE2\\MyIE.exe"="WINXPSP3 256COLOR 640X480 DISABLETHEMES DISABLEDWM HIGHDPIAWARE RUNASADMIN"
```

^ this is the complete path to the program (mabey path is important?) Don't forget the double backslashes when importing a path. The item is a string  Reg_SZ ?

&

Under me as a user (Has to be correct ID thing for the user, this one is munged)

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1019789469-3873768421-1457166851-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]

"C:\\Net\\MyIE2\\MyIE.exe"="WINXPSP3 256COLOR 640X480 DISABLETHEMES DISABLEDWM HIGHDPIAWARE RUNASADMIN"
```

Also a file: some report goes into the system disk at windows/WER/ReportQueue/noncritical, I assume it is just a "log" type of thing.

I do not see anything else important to setting it. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE <-- this location did NOT have anything related changed in it, and I hit the button that said [Change settings for all users].

I set all the flags, for the purpose of seeing all the flags or to use as template.

I have many older programs, and some of them will never run correct under windows7 with any form of compatability, they use slightly different methods of programming, and probably some bad tricks that worked back then, they fail regular.

Comment: thanks for your answer its some what correct, pasting my answer below